# Таймер обратного отсчета. Js & Html

Tags: javascript, html

Есть кнопка. При нажатии по ней запускается обратный таймер. Время указываемое в переменной. При закрытии страницы, браузера. Выключении пк. Значение должно сохранятся, и идти. Можно ли это реализовать? На html & Js

Comment: интеено как оно идити будет вы выключеном пк

Comment: Я спросил. Можно ли это реализовать.

Comment: Таймер без проблем но вопрос ты сам подумай как он будет работать если нет питания

Comment: Запись данных в хранилище браузера, сверка данных. При перезаходе.

Comment: Т.е вышел записались данные, зашёл они сверились и таймеры приняли нужный показатель.

Comment: @Pevel вот при перезаходе вычитай количество секунд, которые прошли с момента записи на момент включения и продолжай отсчет

Comment: да  но у вас написано должен идти когда выключаем Как  не понимаю

Comment: Да вот именно что я совершенно js не знаю. Может кто код готовый кинет. А так спасибо. Буду пытаться

Comment: "Значение должно сохранятся, и идти." - спасибо за хорошее настроение.

Comment: Да ладно вам. Все поняли про что я))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нельзя реализовать работу js таймера после закрытия браузера.

Можно запоминать текущее время системы, работать с ним. Результат и данные можно сохранять в localstorage, после запуска браузера брать сохраненное значение от туда.

```
var now = new Date();

localStorage.setItem(key, value);
keyName = localStorage.key(key);
```

Другого пути нет.